# Google Maps API v3 work with application/xhtml+xml

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, coldfusion

I'm trying to get my ColdFusion file to work with content MIME type **application/xhtml+xml**, because its a mobile website

Its this line of code that is the problem, Google maps will display if this `<cfcontent type="application/xhtml+xml" reset="yes">` is not within the code but I need it within, it declares itself when validated but prevents Google map's JavaScript link from working.

```
    <cfcontent type="application/xhtml+xml" reset="yes">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd">

<cfset MyXmlFile = Expandpath("events.xml")>
<cffile action="READ" variable="xmlInput"  file="#MyXmlFile#">
<cfset MyXmlFile = Expandpath("venue.xsl")>
<cffile action="READ" variable="xslInput" file="#MyXmlFile#">
<cfset xmlOutput = XMLTransform(xmlInput, xslInput)>
<!--- data is output --->
<cfhtmlhead text='<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8"/>#chr(13)##chr(10)#'>
<cfhtmlhead text='<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=200"/>#chr(13)##chr(10)#'>
<cfhtmlhead text='<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>#chr(13)##chr(10)#'>
<cfhtmlhead text='<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAmqAHpxEBuUgTrTW51oqPrczgfls_kttA&amp;sensor=true"></script>#chr(13)##chr(10)#'>
<cfhtmlhead text='<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>#chr(13)##chr(10)#'>
<cfhtmlhead text='<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>#chr(13)##chr(10)#'>

<cfoutput>#xmloutput#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT, Doctype and Google-Map v3 not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556321/xslt-doctype-and-google-map-v3-not-working)

Comment: I don't think you would include the api's and scripts with your xmloutput. What is it you're trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Im just trying to get MIME type application/xhtml+xml to work with Google Maps, it prevents it from displaying

Comment: It works fine if I take it out, and leave it as text/html

Comment: I'm not being clear. You've declared a Doctype, which ultimately should be all you need for mobile to render this correctly. What you don't have is a complete html/xhtml file. You would need opening and closing head and body tags. That is, unless the xml transformation includes them (not usually the case, but can happen).

Comment: Yes this is to do with a xml transformation

This ColdFusion is just the transformation file, from my XML and XSLT file

Comment: Rather than using the cfhtmlhead tags here, you should be able to just write in the head tag, with all the meta, link, and script tags, by hand. Unless the xmltransformation is doing all of this for you, at which point you might want to output your transformed content prior to calling the cfhtmlhead tags. The one Content-Type meta tag should take care of your needs, without having to include the cfcontent tag at all.

Comment: _"stop Google maps JavaScript from working"_ isn't very meaningful - are there any errors in the console? What browsers are you checking this with? If it works without the cfcontent then why do you need it?

Comment: @Peter I have fixed that typo sorry

Comment: I need it since the validator system I have to use ready.mobi won't read that I have declared it unless stated, otherwise it thinks its text/html, just putting meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8 does not work with this system I have to use. Which is why I have to put cfcontent tag above the doctype

Comment: It's not that there was a typo (or rather, bad grammar - a [typo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typo) is a slip of the finger, not simply writing something badly), it's what you're not saying. If something doesn't work it means unexpected behaviour is occuring - you've (still) not fully described how that undesired behaviour manifests itself - i.e. what browsers are involved, do they all act the same, are they giving any indication of error in their consoles, etc.

Comment: So does the validator work ok when you have the cfcontent line there? - if so, a workaround/hack would be to only use the cfcontent for the ready.mobi user agent. Obviously not the best solution, but may or not be worth considering.

Comment: @peter yes it does work, it picks up the MIME type application/xhtml+xml

Comment: Despite your code validating correctly, I suspect you might be running in to compatibility issues with your user agent.  Once you declare your MIME type application/xhtml+xml, most browsers will run in "strict" mode, which means that Javascript's .innerHTML functions will not work.  Google maps uses this extensively to perform document writes.  I suggest content negotiation for the user agent as the DTD you have specified does not specify the MIME type.    Additional reading here: http://www.schillmania.com/content/entries/2004/10/24/application-xhtml+xml/